# Run a ncurses program through a external terminal with CLion in Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, ncurses, manjaro

I tried to run this ncurses software using CLion, but I get an error saying "Error opening terminal: unknown." follow by exit status -1 or something like that when I try to run.

Is there a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Don't expect us to guess what "this ncurses software using Clion" is (which ncurses software, something you have written, or the package or is there a binary executable???) . Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: It is something I have written and is running fine in another IDE. The error seems that the CLion can't open my code ( a game) in the Manjaro terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you that the [environment variable `TERM` is not set](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/ncurses/base/lib_initscr.c#L67).  There may be additional problems if you are not actually running in a *terminal*.

Comment: This same code was running fine in another IDE, so I think that ins't the case. Thanks for the help. :) Here's the SS error: http://i.imgur.com/g6NibaF.png

Comment: I added a link to the relevant part of ncurses.

Comment: I don't understand what you expect me to do, sorry. :(

Comment: You'd get the message if `TERM` is not set.